# Использование библиотеки FileDownloader

Tags: java, android

Всё сделал по инструкции и выходит ошибка:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Please invoke the FileDownloader#init in Application#onCreate first.
```

По ошибке понятно, что надо инициализировать класс `FileDownloader`.
Но код инициализации у меня стоит. Ставил вместо `getApplicationContext(), this`, такая же ошибка.
Вот код кнопки на которую кликаю, для скачивания:

```
FileDownloader.init(getApplicationContext());

final FileDownloadListener queueTarget = new FileDownloadListener() {
      @Override
      protected void pending(BaseDownloadTask task, int soFarBytes, int totalBytes) {}

      @Override
      protected void connected(BaseDownloadTask task, String etag, boolean isContinue, int soFarBytes, int totalBytes) {}

      @Override
      protected void progress(BaseDownloadTask task, int soFarBytes, int totalBytes) {}

      @Override
      protected void blockComplete(BaseDownloadTask task) {}

      @Override
      protected void retry(final BaseDownloadTask task, final Throwable ex, final int retryingTimes, final int soFarBytes) {}

      @Override
      protected void completed(BaseDownloadTask task) {}

      @Override
      protected void paused(BaseDownloadTask task, int soFarBytes, int totalBytes) {}

      @Override
      protected void error(BaseDownloadTask task, Throwable e) {}

      @Override
      protected void warn(BaseDownloadTask task) {}
 };
     FileDownloader.getImpl().create("https://pp.vk.me/c7001/v7001597/2006f/s-Hx1H7aMog.jpg")
                        .setPath(getFilesDir().toString())
                        .setListener(queueTarget)
                        .addHeader("Name","Value")
                        .start();
```

Библиотека в `GitHub` https://github.com/lingochamp/FileDownloader

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Написано же

> Please invoke the FileDownloader#init in Application#onCreate first.

Перенесите `FileDownloader.init(...)` в `onCreate` класса, наследующего `Application` и пропишите в манифесте:

```
<application
    android:name=".AppYourClassName"
    ...
>
```

Ссылки в пример: [класс проекта](https://github.com/lingochamp/FileDownloader/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/liulishuo/filedownloader/demo/DemoApplication.java) и [манифест проекта](https://github.com/lingochamp/FileDownloader/blob/master/demo/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)